# I have tried to drag and drop an element. Why won't my code work properly?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

```
<html>
<head>
<title> test </title>
<script>
var dragObject = null ;
var mouseStartCoords = null ;
var mouseTargetCoords = null ;
var initPosition = null ;

function makeDraggable(item) {
    if(!item){
        return false ;
    }
    item.onmousedown = function(ev) {
        dragObject = this ;
        initPosition = getPosition(item) ;
        if (!initPosition) return false ;
        mouseStartCoords = getMouseCoords(ev) ;
    }
}

function getPosition(e){
    if(!e){
        return false ;
    }
    return {
        x:e.offsetLeft, y:e.offsetTop
    };
}

function getMouseCoords(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event ;
    return {
        x:ev.clientX, y:ev.clientY
    };
}

function mouseMove(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event ;
    var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement ;
    mouseTargetCoords = getMouseCoords(ev) ;
    if (dragObject){
        target.style.position = 'absolute' ;
        target.style.top = initPosition.y + mouseTargetCoords.y - mouseStartCoords.y ;
        target.style.left = initPosition.x + mouseTargetCoords.x - mouseStartCoords.x ;     
    }
}


function mouseUp(ev) {
    dragObject = false ;
}


document.onmouseup = mouseUp ;
document.onmousemove = mouseMove ;

window.onload = function() {
    makeDraggable(document.getElementById('dragObj')) ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="1.jpg" id="dragObj" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens and what do you want to happen? Please provide more information and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Answer (score 1):

error on this line `ev = ev || windown.event ;` change it to `ev = ev || window.event ;`

after this change it works. But not smoothly, reason

```
function mouseMove(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event ;
    var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement ;
    mouseTargetCoords = getMouseCoords(ev) ;
    if (dragObject){
        target.style.position = 'absolute' ;
        target.style.top = initPosition.y + mouseTargetCoords.y - mouseStartCoords.y ;
        target.style.left = initPosition.x + mouseTargetCoords.x - mouseStartCoords.x ;     
    }
}

document.onmousemove = mouseMove ;
```

Which means when mouse is not over image (happens when u drag fast than script can execute) then event.srcElement becomes document whose position u r trying to get.

**EDIT**

Following changes needed to run properly

```
function makeDraggable(item) {
    if(!item){
        return false ;
    }
    item.onmousedown = function(ev) {
        dragObject = item ;
        initPosition = getPosition(item) ;
        if (!initPosition) return false ;
        mouseStartCoords = getMouseCoords(ev) ;
    }
}

function mouseMove(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event ;
    var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement ;
    mouseTargetCoords = getMouseCoords(ev) ;
    if (dragObject){
        dragObject.style.position = 'absolute' ;
        dragObject.style.top = initPosition.y + mouseTargetCoords.y - mouseStartCoords.y ;
        dragObject.style.left = initPosition.x + mouseTargetCoords.x - mouseStartCoords.x ;     
    }
}

function mouseUp(ev) {
    dragObject = null ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you probably want to prevent the browser's default action so that it doesn't try to do browser native image dragging.

Inside the `onmousedown` handler, you probably want something like this:

```
    ev = ev || window.event ;
    if (ev.preventDefault) {
      ev.preventDefault() ;
    }
    ev.returnValue = false ;
    dragObject = this ;
    initPosition = getPosition(item) ;
    if (!initPosition) return false ;
    mouseStartCoords = getMouseCoords(ev) ;
```

People are most familiar with default behaviors as they relate to links.  For an anchor tag, the browser's default action when the link is clicked is to navigate to the href.  To stop this, you use `preventDefault()` (or IE's equivalent, setting `returnValue` to `false`).

Browsers also have default actions for other activities, such as dragging images around.  In the case of dragging an image, some browsers will create a semi-opaque ghost image that you can drag around.

Comment: did you get this figured out?